# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i have a problem with my laravel project

> Trying to get property of non-object

Problem in this line

```
<div class="text">{{ link_to_route('forum.show',$question->title,array($question->id)) }}</div>
```

and

```
{{ $question->created_at->diffforHumans()}} bởi {{ $question->user->name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure you have valid objects in variables and not nulls, probably something like this would work:

```
@if ($question)
   {{ link_to_route('forum.show',$question->title,array($question->id)) }}

   {$question->created_at->diffforHumans()}} bởi 
   @if ($question->user)
      {{ $question->user->name }}
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Oh, i got it :D i forgot to replace my old table by my new table :D thank you  so much